# PHP - Filtering date keys in array

Tags: php, arrays

I've been having trouble for a while now trying to filter my results based on the dates in the array. For example, I want to create an invoice system with a user specified amount of years to search for invoices. So if I specified 3 years, it would only bring back 3 years of invoices.

My invoice array looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Invoice_Array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2884
                    [1] => 15/08/2013
                    [2] => C
                    [3] => -61.54
                    [4] => 0.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2719
                    [1] => 13/06/2012
                    [2] => C
                    [3] => -200.00
                    [4] => 0.00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 99900
                    [1] => 02/03/2011
                    [2] => I
                    [3] => 50.00
                    [4] => 0.00
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5685
                    [1] => 02/03/2011
                    [2] => C
                    [3] => -50.00
                    [4] => 0.00
                )

        )

    [Invoice_Count] => 4
)
```

I've tried using this from another questions answer:

```
foreach ($myarray as $item)
    if ($item->dateitem >= $startDate  &&  
        $item->dateitem <= $endDate)
            $newarray[] = $item;
```

But I'm having trouble implementing it for my array above. What would be a good way to go 'into' the array at the dates, and then filter the results so that all the other data is still present, except for the keys outside of the date range? (So if I only wanted 3 years of data back from now, only key [0] would be there).

I think the first thing to work out would be how to check the date in each key/invoice against the date range specified. Perhaps a foreach that loops through the invoices, and an if statement that checks if the current pointer position is in that date range somehow?

Finished:

```
$years = 3;
$myarray = array(
    'Invoice_Count' => 6,
    'Invoice_List' => array(
        array('31515', 'I', '255.60', '255.60', '15/06/2015'),
        array('31664', 'I', '330.00', '330.00', '22/07/2015'),
        array('31675', 'I', '4088.40', '4088.40', '27/07/2015'),
        array('31650', 'I', '245.70', '245.70', '29/07/2010')
        ),
    );

$newarray = array();
$boundary = strtotime('today -'.$years.' year');
foreach ($myarray['Invoice_List'] as $item) {
    $parts = explode('/', $item[4]);
    $date = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%0d', $parts[2], $parts[1], $parts[0]);
    if (strtotime($date)>$boundary)
            $newarray[] = $item;
}
print_r(strtotime($date)); echo " - "; print_r($boundary);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newarray); echo "</pre>";
```

Thanks a lot to syck!

Comment: What is `$startDate` and `$endDate` over here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10668264/4978704 it was this question. I'm not sure sadly.

Comment: How do you get the value `3 Years` from the user?

Comment: @PrerakSola As an integer of "3", they type it into my plug-in at the WordPress control panel. So we can just assume its `$years = 3;` for sake of example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your date is represented by `dd/mm/YYYY` and therefore not in a format recognized by strtotime(). So you should do something like

```
$parts = explode('/', $date);
$date = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%0d', $parts[2], $parts[1], $parts[0]);
```

Keep an eye on the difference between "three years back" (back to august 18th 2012) and "the last three years" (2012-2014).

As an example, if you want to go $years years back:

```
$newarray = array();
$boundary = strotime('today minus '.$years.' year');
foreach ($myarray as $item) {
    $parts = explode('/', $item[1]);
    $date = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%0d', $parts[2], $parts[1], $parts[0]);
    if ($strtotime($date)>$boundary)
            $newarray[] = $item;
}
```

to collect the selected entries of `$myarray` in the new array `$newarray`.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean by "three years back", good point, it should indeed be 'today minus $years'. Thanks a lot for this help, I'll have a play with it and get back to you.

Comment: Got it working with the code I've added to my question. Thanks a lot!!